# macro in node option

Tags: pgfkeys

I use `\pgfkeys` of `tikz` to define something(please see the following MWE), but the simple code can not compile.I guess wrong way of using the macro `\ifthenelse` in \pgfkeys is the cause. But why and how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{%
    tp/.code=\def\tp{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
        {centered}%
        {above=#1}%
      },
      tp/.default={},
      mydraw/.code={\tikz\draw(0,0)--node[#1]{node}(1,0);}
  }
\pgfkeys{tp,mydraw/.expanded={\tp}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \ifthenelse is not expandable.

Comment: Why /.expanded can not expand \ifthenelse, and how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expanded` can only expand commands that are expandable. `\ifthenelse` is not such a command and so won't work. An expandable test exists e.g. in expl3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\pgfkeys{%
    tp/.code=\def\tp{%
      \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}
        {centered}
        {above=#1}
      },
      tp/.default={},
      mydraw/.code={\tikz\draw(0,0)--node[#1]{node}(1,0);}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff  
\pgfkeys{tp,mydraw/.expanded={\tp}}

\pgfkeys{tp=4pt,mydraw/.expanded={\tp}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. And is there any solution other than expl3?

Comment: `\ifstrempty` from etoolbox works too. But expl3 is more powerful, and it is easier to see if a command is expandable or not: the documentation has nice red stars.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code and info! I'll try both.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that does not use extra packages (and is rather close to what Ti*k*Z uses internally, if I am not mistaken). I had to trade your `tp/.default={}` for `tp/.default=\empty` (and if I am not mistaken, Ti*k*Z uses internally `\pgfutil@empty` for that but I didn't want to add `\makeatletter`s here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{%
    tp/.code={\ifx#1\empty\relax
        \def\tp{centered}%\typeout{empty}
        \else
        \def\tp{above=#1}%\typeout{#1\space is\space not\space empty}
        \fi
      },
      tp/.default=\empty,
      mydraw/.code={\tikz\draw(0,0)--node[#1]{node}(1,0);}
  }
\pgfkeys{tp,mydraw={\tp}}

\pgfkeys{tp=5pt,mydraw/.expanded={\tp}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marnot. I love this version of solution. By the way, contrast to your code, why this is a wrong way--`tp/.code={\def\tp{\ifx#1\empty\relax centered \else above=#1 \fi}, `? Does that mean \ifx is unexpandable? And what's the difference between `\empty` and `{}`?

Comment: @lyl First of all, I do not know these things at the level Ulrike Fischer does. It seems to me, though, a bit worrisome that in your construction the parser would have to hold back the expansion of `\def`. Some TeX gurus will be able to fix this with tons of `\expandafter`s, `\noexpand`s or so, but I am not one of those. I am just a marmot. As for `{}` vs. `\empty`: the curly braces are tricky since only experts know when they are taken into account. E.g. `\savebox{\mybox}{...}` and `\savebox\mybox{...}` seem to do the same. So I personally switched to `\empty`, and this seems to work.

Comment: Thank you @marnot for your solution and further explanations!